# Implementing both SAML and legacy login without Spring Security API

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027961/can-i-implement-both-saml-and-basic-spring-security-within-an-application) one however our application (which makes use of only Spring Beans & Annotations) currently does not use the Spring Security component/API. Would like to know if we can support the plain vanilla login (based on username password) mechanism for one set of users and support SAML based logins for another set of users (thereby using only Spring SAML extension). Or is there some basic Spring security config to incorporate before we use the SAML extension? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact possible to use Spring SAML extension without 'implementing' the Spring security aspect in the project. However the spring security jars are needed as a dependency.