# How to implement multiple Auth flow, like SAML, openId Connect, etc. in the same Spring Application(Not Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement Azure AD SSO using SAML, as well as Okta SSO with OpenID Connect. Additionally, I also need a form-based login that uses JWT tokens to authorize APIs in my Spring application. I have read through multiple articles and documentation, but I have been unable to figure out how to do it. If anyone has experience with this and can offer some guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Following are some of the articles I gonna through:-

https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-multi-tenancy-using-java-spring-boot-spring
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182738/combine-database-and-saml-authentication-in-one-application-using-spring-securit?noredirect=1&lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `SecurityFilterChain` bean for each request authorization mechanism.

When you want several security filterchains, do the following:

- name it differently (`basicAuthFilterChain`, `oauth2ClientFilterChain`, `oauth2ResourceServerFilterChain`, etc.)
- decorate each with different `@Order`
- all but the las one in order (the one with the highest value) must declare a `securityMatcher` to define to which requests it applies to (can be on path, headers, or about whatever is in the request)

##### Note

When using `oauth2Login`, requests are authorized with session cookies, not `Bearer` token (JWTs) in authorization header. Just open your browser debugging tools on a Spring application configured as **OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`**, you'll find a session cookie but no `Authorization` header. Access token is stored in the session (on the server) and is intended to be used to send queries to **resource servers**.